# How to add json object into another json object at the same level?

Tags: java, json, 4gl

suppose that i have json object

```
"body" : -{
    "clinic" : -{
         "address" : -{
         "city" : Costa Mesa,
         "state" : CA      
          }
```

I want to add 'doctor' json object with its children as the same level as clinic in the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the JSONObject of the body and put the doctor

```
 ((JSONObject) yourJson.get("body")).put("doctor", doctorJSON);
```

Comment: what if i have to add json object in between of two children.